# How to verify DFS replication for EVERY file?

Tags: windows, replication, dfs, verification

Was wondering if there is a way to verify that every single file from the source server is replicated over to the secondary server.

I understand there's a command [`Get-DfsrFileHash`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dfsr/get-dfsrfilehash) that can verify the files are sync'ed but I'm working with about 6 TB of company data which is too many files to verify with that command.

The reason why I need to verify is because I'm planning on deleting the primary volumes and point the users to the secondary server but I need to make sure all the files are replicated over to this before I switch them over.

Comment: The question was from 2 years ago. Could you share how you eventually solved this?

Answer (score 2):

## Create a Diagnostic Report

1. Open `DFS Management` from the start menu.
2. Expand `Replication`.

   a. Note: You may need to right click and then click on `Add Replication Groups to Display...`
3. Right Click the Replication Group and select `Create Diagnostic Report...`
4. Select `Health report`. Click `Next`.
5. Choose a Path to save the report to, Next.
6. Select Servers to Include/Exclude, Next.
7. Select the Server with the most up to date records (Reference Member)

   a. Be sure the check `Count the replicated files and their sizes on each member`
8. Click `Finish` and view the report in a browser, it should have all the info you need.

I also recommend using [`robocopy`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy)  for this type of need.

#### Further reading

- Windows Server 2008. Includes screenshots.

  - SearchWindowsServer, Brien Posey, 2010-04, [*Monitoring Windows DFS health with diagnostic reports*](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Monitoring-Windows-DSF-health-with-diagnostic-reports) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/QE2eU).)
- Windows Server 2008 R2. Includes screenshots further down the page.

  - Microsoft TechNet, India Support Team blog, 2011-08-16, [*Log collection for DFSR replication issues*](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msindiasupp/2011/08/16/log-collection-for-dfsr-replication-issues/) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/w7qCZ).)
- Windows Server 2012. Includes screenshots.

  - AskME4Tech blog, 2016-11-11, [*How can monitoring DFS Replication in Windows Server 2012*](http://www.askme4tech.com/how-can-monitoring-dfs-replication-windows-server-2012) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/yuAa8).)

Comment: I understand the report shows the number of files on each replicated folder but even if the numbers are exactly the same, this doesn't mean the two replicated folders have the exact same files. I guess this is good enough though to use as an indicator to see how similar the replicated folders are.

Comment: If there are files that can not/were not coppied they will show up as an error. I've not ever seen this report not account for missing or out of date files.